# No application remembers its user data | Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, firefox, chromium

All applications in my Ubuntu 16.04 seem to lost track of their user data.

When I launch firefox, none of my bookmarks/browsing history are present. Launching `chromium-browser` from the terminal shows:

> `[3558:3558:1111/200649:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(966)] Failed
>   to create socket directory.
>   [3558:3558:1111/200649:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1516)] Failed to
>   create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that
>   running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes
>   rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now
>   to avoid profile corruption`

and fails to launch.

The dash shows

> There's nothing that matches your search

MEGAsync has shown a pop-up window asking for login details, whereas it used to automatically sync my files with the cloud(it was logged in and I never used to require to login again).

When I googled around, I got an idea that all the application data stored for this particular user that I'm logged in inside Ubuntu might have been lost, but when I showed the hidden files in my home folder, I found all of them intact at their usual locations. For example, `about:profiles` in firefox shows its Root directory as `/home/user/.mozilla/firefox/73h5bi5y.default` which is intact with data of the browsing history and extensions.

I got this problem abruptly while I was using my computer. I had just chosen to restart firefox, and it opened up with a blank bookmarks bar, no history and no passwords. Even synapse search isn't working as it has lost all of its indexed data of files and folders across all partitions.

---

UPDATE::
I tried downloading a small image from firefox, and it said:

> There is not enough room on the disk to save .
>   Remove unnecessary files from the disk and try again, or try saving in a 
>   different location.

When I right clicked into my home directory, it showed zero bytes of free space. That's not true. I don't know how to prove that as I'm not able to access `Disk Management` through Dash as it's not showing any applications/its search ain't working.

---

Here's the output to `df -h` : 
[image]

Comment: please, open a terminal and enter 'df -h' add the output to your question.

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann I have added the output

Comment: is one of /home or /home/user a symlink to either /mn/8CA0FE5AA0FE49EA, /think, /mash or /cargo? or is it placed on / - all of those mount points are (nearly/completely) full.

Comment: no, the disk spaces of other drives are correct. One thing that has come to my notice, is how for /dev/sda4 it shows a size of 32G and used 30G, with 0 Available. The data for the other directories/folders is believable atleast, as Avail = Size - Used.

Comment: 2GB may be used by metadata through the filesystem. which filesystem is it? usage/free reported by df for btrfs partitions for example is not even close to its real usage/free status.
if you are still in doubt, run fsck for the partitions.

Comment: I had a look at the `df -h` on my system and it had similar issue for ext4:
/dev/sda1 is reported as being 451G big, with 187G in use and 241G free. when subtracting 187G from 451G one would expect to have 264G free.

Comment: As far as I remember, /dev/sda4 had more than a GB of storage free for sure. The free space surely went down to zero as soon as this problem (applications losing their app data) happened.